# How to delete all general_log entries in Google Cloud SQL?

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I have a Google Cloud SQL 2nd generation instance I recently created. I initially had the slow query and general logs turned on. I exported the DBs from an instance in another region and imported them to this new instance, but the size of the new instance is nearly double the old one, and I believe this is due to the logs created during the import, tho just trying to get a count of entries seems to just hang.

I have turned off the general log now, but how can I clear it? I have tried both truncating and deleting, and neither work.

```
mysql> truncate mysql.general_log;
ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation

mysql> delete from mysql.general_log;
ERROR 1556 (HY000): You can't use locks with log tables.
```

I have given my user all the permissions I can, but unlike the 1st gen Cloud SQL instances, I cannot give SUPER (and even root doesn't have it).

Any suggestions on how to clear this?

Answer (score 1):

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/admin-api/v1beta4/instances/truncateLog is the API that truncates the general log. However, Cloud SQL now supports streaming general query log to Cloud Logging; that's the recommended approach instead of logging to table.